# How to replace slow 'apply' method in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I have a DataFrame with currencies transactions:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[1653663281618, -583.8686, 'USD'],
       [1653741652125, -84.0381, 'USD'],
       [1653776860252, -33.8723, 'CHF'],
       [1653845294504, -465.4614, 'CHF'],
       [1653847155140, 22.285, 'USD'],
       [1653993629537, -358.04640000000006, 'USD']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data = data, columns = ['time', 'qty', 'currency_1'])
```

I need to add new column "balance" which would calculate the sum of the column 'qty' for all previous transactions. I have a simple function:

```
def balance(row):
    table = df[(df['time'] < row['time']) & (df['currency_1'] == row['currency_1'])]
    return table['qty'].sum()

df['balance'] = df.apply(balance, axis = 1)
```

But my real DataFrame is very large and .apply method works extremely slow.
Is it a way to avoid using apply function in this case?
Something like np.where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use pandas [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) here:

**EDIT**
After adding a condition:
I don't know how `transform` performs compared to `apply`, I'd say just try it on your real data. Can't think of an easier solution for the moment.

```
df['balance'] = df.groupby('currency_1')['qty'].transform(lambda x: x.shift().cumsum())
print(df)

            time       qty currency_1   balance
0  1653663281618 -583.8686        USD       NaN
1  1653741652125  -84.0381        USD -583.8686
2  1653776860252  -33.8723        CHF       NaN
3  1653845294504 -465.4614        CHF  -33.8723
4  1653847155140   22.2850        USD -667.9067
5  1653993629537 -358.0464        USD -645.6217
```

old answer:

```
df['Balance'] = df['qty'].shift(fill_value=0).cumsum()
print(df)

            time       qty currency_1    Balance
0  1653663281618 -583.8686        USD     0.0000
1  1653741652125  -84.0381        USD  -583.8686
2  1653776860252  -33.8723        USD  -667.9067
3  1653845294504 -465.4614        USD  -701.7790
4  1653847155140   22.2850        USD -1167.2404
5  1653993629537 -358.0464        USD -1144.9554
```

Comment: Deleted my answer because I forgot to consider that the qty column should be shifted down one.  This answer is better.

Comment: @ZachFlanders Thanks. After seeing your answer, I instantly checked OP's way again with apply :D Thought maybe I was wrong

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, I should have mentioned that just cumsum would not work, as there could be other conditions. I have edited my questions, would you be so kind to check it? In this case I have 2 different currencies.

Comment: @Olga I updated my answer, please try it on your real data

Comment: @Rabinzel, Thank you, it works much faster than apply!